# Is there any application like amazing slow downer for window or Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any application like amazing `slow downer` for window or Mac?

Some of the features:

- Change the speed of the music - from 20% (one fifth speed) to 200% (double speed) without changing the pitch.
- Wrong key? Change the pitch in semi-tones - at full or changed speed.
- Out of tune? Adjust the pitch in cents (100ths of a semi-tone) to suit your instrument.
- Real-time processing - all described above is done in real-time - just insert the CD and press the play button!
- Also slows down MP3, Wave, Windows Media Audio, Ogg, FLAC and AAC/M4A files on your computer in real-time. Note: M4P files from the iTunes store is now supported.

http://www.ronimusic.com/amsldowin.htm

Comment: Not as detailed, but vlc does have slowdown/speedup options.

Comment: So does smplayer. Evergreen: If that website goes down this question becomes hard to answer. It is generally a better idea to copy/paste some of the content of the website over and keep the link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind for help making more clarification, I like it. Also thank you Karthik. I studied both VLC and smplayer, they help for a little speed change, but not specific and have no pitch change too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Audacity (available in the software centre).

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Change_Speed

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Change_Pitch

And about a million other things :)

There are ones with even more features available but Audacity is the simplest to use I think.

That program you talk about (Amazing Slow Downer) may run in WINE if you can't find anything else that meets your needs.  It doesn't look like a very complicated application.

Answer (score 6):

It look like I've found out the right thing. It's the app [Play it slowly](http://29a.ch/playitslowly)

[image]

Play it slowly is a light weight application but has a simple , clean interface. It is simple to use and has basic features such as:

Slow the speed on playback without altering pitch.
Easily mark, move, and reset sections of a track for playback.
Easy to start/stop/restart playback.
Play is slowly is in the [Debian and Ubuntu repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/playitslowly)

sudo apt-get install playitslowly

The above information is quoted the post: [Music practice](http://blog.bodhizazen.com)

by the author bodhi.zazen.

Comment: This is a great choice! I installed it on linux Mint 19 with no issues, and it works like a charm! Thank You! :)